# Ensuring files are closed in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I have classes that can take a file as an argument, for example:

```
ParserClass(file('/some/file', 'rb'))
```

If I understand Python correctly, the file will be closed automatically once the object is garbage collected. What I don't understand is exactly when that happens. In a function like:

```
def parse_stuff(filename):
    parser = ParserClasss(file(filename, 'rb'))

    return list(parser.info())
```

Shouldn't that `parser` object be GC'd immediately after the function exits, causing the file to be closed? Yet, for some reason, Python appears to have the file open long after the function exits. Or at least it looks that way because Windows won't let me modify the file, claiming Python has it open and forcing me to to close IDLE.

Is there a way to ensure files are closed, short of explicitly asking for it for every file I create? I also want to add that these classes are external, I don't want to dig through them to find out exactly what they with the file.

Comment: It's worth noting that [``file()`` is not designed for opening files](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#file), use [``open()``](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) instead!

Comment: Change `ParserClass` to accept the path to the file and have `ParserClass` handle the openning and closing of the file, using the `with` statement to ensure the file is closed properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `with` to open files.  When you use `with`, the file will be implicitly closed when the `with` block is exited, and it will handle exception states as well.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the fact that ``with`` also handles exceptions well - it's a really important point.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `with` statement to open the file, which will ensure that the file is closed.

```
with open('/some/file', 'rb') as f:
    parser = ParserClasss(f)
    return list(parser.info())
```

See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/ for more details.

Comment: I know I can do this. I was wondering if there was a shortcut or some way to close all open files.

Comment: @Confluence No, you cannot. The only thing Python (or any other GC'd language for that matter) can figure out automatically is when an object cannot possibly be in use anymore, and even then it may only notice that long after it becomes unreachable. Even if it *could* always detect unreachability immediately, that's still not (consider `f = open(...); read_but_dont_close(f); do_a_lot_of_work()`). Just get used to `with`. Even ignoring the technical benefits, it makes the period of use explicit, and explicit is better than implicit.